# Update apt-get cache only if it's older than certain time

Tags: debian, scripting, apt

I'm on debian. I would like to execute an apt-get update (and maybe something else) only if the time since last update is bigger or smaller than a certain amount **with a straight command, no cron tricks or similar**.

**Let's assume I know nothing about apt-get previous state**, an update could have been never issued since the os installation, or triggered manually 2 mins ago, or issued automatically by unattended-upgrades service.

Eg.

```
if(time > 30 min) apt-get update
if(time > 2 days) something else
```

This question is similar to another I found in askubuntu but due the different setup in debian config I can't find a timestamp file informing me when the last update command took place.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The file `/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin` is regenerated each time `apt-get update` runs (and isn't regenerated otherwise).

For example, if you want to run `apt-get update` only if it hasn't been run in the past hour, you can use

```
#!/bin/sh
last_update=$(stat -c %Y /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin)
now=$(date +%s)
if [ $((now - last_update)) -gt 3600 ]; then
  apt-get update
fi
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$(find /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin -mmin -60)" ]; then
  apt-get update
fi
```

Note that if you run multiple copies of this script almost at the same time, they might all decide to run `apt-get update`. If that's a concern, use a lock (which is a wholly separate issue).

Comment: Please extend your answer with a full working code to take advantage of this info. What should to be done with this file? Get the creation (or the modified) date in seconds, do the actual time minus that dat in seconds and make a comparison? What if this file was never created? eg: debian plain installed from cd and never issued an update.. please cover this aspects in the answer, thanks :)

Comment: @user3450548 That's one way, though calling `find` is more direct. I've added code snippets to my answer.

Comment: On my system (Debian sid, apt 2.5.2), the file `pkgcache.bin` is also updated when a package is installed. So it's not a bullet-proof indicator for `apt update`.

Answer (score 3):

Building on the [existing answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/271058/9340) back form 2016 (5 years+), it is that on debian stable (version 11) and oldstable (v. 10) the file `/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin` must not exist:

```
+ cat /etc/debian_version
10.11
```

a working replacement (as in find) was for me:

```
if [ -z "$(find /var/cache/apt -maxdepth 0 -mmin -60)" ]; then
  apt-get update              
fi
```

Take note on `find(1)`s `-maxdepth 0` argument and value.

---

The original answer still answers this in regard of my understanding of the original meaning that a flag-file (or directory) time information can be used to conditionally call the `apt-get update` command.

This is likely due to changes with `apt-get(8)`, but I could not fully review the changes (e.g. since which version it changed) for this answer and it only reflects my personal, practical experience. YMMV.

---

This answer is with the caveat to rely on time information of a directory node. I'd consider this degrading compared to a file node (which it was earlier). Review the file-system specifics when applying such changes. YMMV.

---

References:

- [Update apt-get cache only if it's older than certain time (existing answer by *Gilles 'SO- stop being evil'*)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/271058/9340)
- [2.2.1. apt vs. apt-get / apt-cache vs. aptitude (Debian package management)](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_literal_apt_literal_vs_literal_apt_get_literal_literal_apt_cache_literal_vs_literal_aptitude_literal)

Answer (score 0):

Like other answers say, modification time of `/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin` is the indicator, but that file won't exist initially on recent versions of Ubuntu.

So here's a short `is_modified_within_minutes` func I came up with, and how to use it:

```bash
is_modified_within_minutes() { test -f "$1" && test -z "$(find "$1" -mmin +$2)"; }

is_modified_within_minutes /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin 1440 || sudo apt-get update
```

Of course, make sure only one instance of this code is running, like others have pointed out.